# Application/Json error when sending Gmail with Postman

Tags: json, header, postman, request-headers

I'm trying to send a Gmail with Postman but got this error:

[image]

These are my configured headers:

[image]

I have configured everything needed on Google Cloud engine (Oauth permissions, certifications...etc), read similar posts, and also tried testing from gmail API playground and everything was ok:

[image]

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong at the first glance. Is `raw` properly formatted in base64 including from to and subject fields of the email? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message

Comment: To debug it more, you can see console in Postman, or channel it through a proxy. It might give you more hints than just looking at the gui in Postman.

Comment: Yes, raw is properly formatted in base64. Nothing suspicious in the Postman console other than the mentioned error.

Comment: Just being overly suspicious now, but if you delete your custom `Content-Type` header and let postman fill in the default one you unchecked, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all custome headers , (Create a new request by following below steps)

**Steps:**

1. https://console.developers.google.com/ Goto url and create an API. (by clicking credentials>create credentials)
2. https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/overview Goto url, click credentials> create new 0auth0.2 ( select applicaiton type as Web application)
3. While creating 0auth0.2 scroll down and set Authorized redirect URIs as https://localhost

[image]

4. CLick the download as json and then save the auth
5. Open postman and set authorization as 0auth2.0 from authorization header:
6. Generate new token by filling the content as per the downloaded json ( open the json and fill postman as in json)

[image]

set scope and state as : https://mail.google.com/ ( full access ) see scope at : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

7. In postman Set url as :[https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/praveendvd0pravu%40gmail.com/messages/send?key={YOURAPI_KEY_That_was_generated}](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/praveendvd0pravu%40gmail.com/messages/send?key=%7BYOURAPI_KEY_That_was_generated%7D)
8. goto https://www.base64encode.org/ , and paste below content and click encode. Copy the output.

   From: youremail@gmail.com
   To: tosomeemail@gmail.com
   Subject: Hi

   Hi this is

9): paste it as json body

```
{

"raw":"IEZyb206IHlvdXJlbWFpbEBnbWFpbC5jb20KIFRvOiB0b3NvbWVlbWFpbEBnbWFpbC5jb20KIFN1YmplY3Q6IEhpICAKICAgIApIaSB0aGlzIGlzIA=="

}
```

10. Send it :

[image]