# Which url to send oauth2 access token request?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, postman

At this moment I try to make it work with postmen. I want to get the access token for firebase.

https://service.endpoint.com/api/oauth2/token returns 404

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth? returns a huge amount of random unstructured text which contains no access token

Any hint would be very helpful, I have no idea where to get the right url. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65697747/6793637